# Checking the number of observations for each ID within 8 day periods

Tags: r, count, tidyverse, lubridate

In the data set below, I would like to know how many observations each `ID` has in 8 day chunks. What would be the best way to approach this?

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2013"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"), 300)
ID <-  rep(c("A","B","C"), 50)
deer <- data.frame(date = date,
                   utm_x = runif(length(date), min = 238785, max = 453354.5),
                   utm_y = runif(length(date), min = 4096853.0  , max = 4280487.1 ),
                   ID)

deer$julian <- yday(as.Date(deer$date))
deer$month <- month(deer$date)
deer$year <- year(deer$date)
```

I have been able to get the total number of observations for each `ID`, but I'm unsure on how to see how many observations each ID has within each 8 day period in the data set:

```
# Observation Distribution 
count <- data.frame(table(df$AnimalID))
colnames(count)[1] <- "ID"
```

Comment: Do you want `deer %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(eight_day_period = ceiling_date(date, "8 day")) %>% group_by(eight_day_period, .add = TRUE) %>% summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may create a grouping variable with `ceiling_date` and then get the `count` or `summarise` with `n()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
deer %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(eight_day_period = ceiling_date(date, "8 day")) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  count(ID, eight_day_period)
```